# Is there any way to join two mongo db collection with dynamic collection name?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation, aggregator

I created a ref collection which contains other collection name and document id.

So it looks like

```
{
   refName: "Collection 1",
   refId: "123123",
},
{
   refName: "Collection 2",
   refId: "456734",
}
```

Collection 1 and Collection 2 have the documents with id 123123 and 456734.
In this case, I wanna loop all ref collection and get referenced collection data using mongodb aggregation.

I tried to use $lookup but it is said that $from of $lookup must be string literals, not the variables.

Is there anyway to handle this kind of transaction in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string to int or int to string

```
db.ref.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      refId: {
        "$toInt": "$refId"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "coll1",
      "localField": "refId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "join"
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MsQ08N7kySm) String to Int**

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JMLJM76kqSQ) Int to String with[Uncorrelated-sub-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)**

Comment: thanks for your help. your sample looked great. But I wanted something different.

Comment: so you are now using from with static string literal exactly coll1.
But what I wanna get is set from with coll1 or coll2, the data from db field.

Comment: So you need another lookup to connect coll2 as what I showed you above